# How play a YouTube video in the background on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, youtube

Is there any way to play a YouTube video in the background on iOS 8 so I can have music playing from a video while doing other things with the iPad?

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps:

- Open Safari on your iPad
- Go to www.youtube.com and search for a video
- When the video you choose is playing, press the home button
- The music will stop playing
- Slide from the button to the top (Control Center)
- Press the play button

Normally, you can now hear the audio from your YouTube video..

Comment: I wanted to avoid safari because with this method sometimes the playback just stops and the url is lost so can't be resumed.

Comment: Safari didn't work for me on iOS 9.1 (iPad), the play button just didn't do anything in the Control Center. However, using Google Chrome did work, following this same method.

Comment: w3d's comment worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The app **Music Tube** (with a space, not MusicTube) will play YouTube video and continue playing when put into the background, although the sound drops out briefly when you do so. There are some videos it doesn't seem to be capable of playing though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't download the you tube app, because when you do it automatically goes to the app and then you can't do nothing else

Comment: If you follow a YouTube link (in the browser) then it does seem to persistently want to open in the YouTube app. However, if you enter `www.youtube.com` directly in the browser's address bar then you do seem to be able to avoid the app and use the "browser" instead.

Answer (score 0):

The new [Vox](https://appsto.re/us/gBfN2.i) app for iOS can play audio from YouTube videos in the background.